# What are the types of cultural diplomacy?

Tags: united-states, international-relations

I believe there aren't any types, because cultural diplomacy is a part of public diplomacy but one of my teachers said that sport, for instance, is a type of cultural diplomacy. I can't find any information to confirm that he is right, so what's your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

To steal a [definition](http://www.culturaldiplomacy.org/index.php?en_culturaldiplomacy):

> "Cultural Diplomacy may best be described as a course of actions, which are based on and utilize the exchange of ideas, values, traditions and other aspects of culture or identity, whether to strengthen relationships, enhance socio-cultural cooperation, promote national interests and beyond; Cultural diplomacy can be practiced by either the public sector, private sector or civil society."

So yes, sport is a good example. Something like the Olympics is an excellent example. Where nations get to put their culture on display. Often, internationally hosted events are part of that exchange.The Cannes Film festival might be one. The World Cup another. Any event where a nation gets to express its identity to the world, is a demonstration of Cultural Diplomacy.

> Cultural diplomacy in practice (or applied cultural diplomacy) is the application and implementation of the theory of cultural diplomacy, including all models that have been practiced throughout history by individual, community, state or institutional actors. These models include for example diverse cultural exchange programs, international delegations (e.g., American jazz ambassadors) or sports competitions. The examples are uniquely able to affect intercultural and interfaith understanding and promote reconciliation.

So, for a unique example, the [Hajj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hajj). While unified in faith, the participants are diversified in culture. People gather from around the world and pray. In this process they each exchange cultural ideas and beliefs.

I'm updating my post to include a non-religious / cultural example.

The [International Space Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station) is a good example. Many agencies across many countries collaborating in space exploration. There's also [CERN](https://home.cern/about), which is a collection of Europe's greatest minds coming together to do some physics.

For a much smaller, localized event.. most major cities host international events. I know in Montreal, Canada we have [Just for Laughs](https://www.hahaha.com/en), [Grand Prix](http://www.grandprixmontreal.com/) racing and the [Jazz Festival](https://www.montrealjazzfest.com/). I would say these are indeed small events with some level of cultural diplomacy. Every one of these events has people coming from around the world to take part in the festivals and sharing in the Canadian cultural experience and identity. Canada being a multicultural society, events like those I listed, best demonstrate who we are to the world on a smaller scale. Notice all the festivals have one thing in common: They all bring people from other places to our city. The comedy festival brings comedians from around the world, the racing bring drivers from around the world and the music festival has a lot of local and international talent.